# django: rendering a template field containing html in selector choices

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

This question is about the correct rendering of html in the choices of a selector. Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Test(models.Model):
    area = models.FloatField(choices=((0, '0 mm&sup2;'), (0.5, '0.5 mm&sup2;')), default=0)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import Test

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test

def test(request):
    form = TestForm()
    return render_to_response('test.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

test.html

```
{{ form.area }}
{{ form.area|safe }}
{% autoescape off %}{{ form.area }}{% endautoescape %}
```

None of the above three options succeeds to correctly display the selector choice as **0 mm²** instead of `0 mm&sup2;`. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mark_safe` function to make Django do not escape string in template

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.db import models
class Test(models.Model):
    area = models.FloatField(choices=((0, mark_safe('0 mm&sup2;')), (0.5, mark_safe('0.5 mm&sup2;'))), default=0)
```

Comment: That works perfect. No need for safe filter or autoescape off tag neither. Thanks!